# Where to find a Prism MAUI hello world sample?

Tags: prism, maui

I'm trying to port my [Xamarin Forms with Prism] application to Maui (also with Prism). The Prism for Maui web page promises to enclose some examples, but so far there are no any (for Maui).

Could anyone share a link to any resource describing how to setup properly **Maui** with **Prism** ? On the Prism website there are some concepts described, but the examples enclosed are just few-liners, not covering the things that I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to setup end-to-end Prism with Maui is to install nugget template for Visual Studio, and to create a new project.
First, goto nuget.org and search for "Maui Prism" phrase. Limit the search results ('Package type' on the left) to Template, click 'Apply'.

Install the **Prism.Templates** template locally, by executing CLI installation command, as provided (version number may change over time):
In my case it was:
dotnet new install Prism.Templates::8.1.97

Once installed, open visual studio and create brand new project, selecting Prism .NET MAUI App template. The hello-word application is end-to-end setup and ready to run.

This application may be helpful to carry over missing elements into migrated application from Xamarin-Prism to Maui-Prism.

Comment: Side-note: the documentation at [prismlibrary.com](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/migrating.html) is currently (March 2023) outdated, but the version on [github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Documentation/blob/master/docs/maui/migrating.md) is helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately after install Prism.Templates::8.1.97 create new project it is not work due to error: 'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UsePrismApp'
Where to find any actual documentation about Prism.Maui?

Comment: Prism template: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Templates

Answer (score 0):

[Prism Documentation for .NET MAUI](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/index.html)

You can check out the docs. As it relates to sample project I don't think the team has added a full sample to the main repo yet because they are stabilizing the framework for .NET MAUI. From the documentation the main breaking changes are highlighted, apart from those its the same as prism for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I'd already seen these materials. Problem is these are not complete. For example I can't find info about App.xaml file. Should I use (in Maui with Prism) <Application> element, or similarly as in XF - PrismApplication (If anything like this exists). 
Also, I'm getting Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException (error occurred while resolving INavigationService). Should I call somewhere some kind of "Init" method or register the missing NavigationService ?