# Prism GA Support for MAUI .NET 6.0 on iOS and Android

Tags: maui, prism

I see that the documentation has a section about [Prism for MAUI](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/index.html) including a demo video of an upgraded project. The video talks about Prism.Templates and when I [download the Prism.Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700236/where-to-find-a-prism-maui-hello-world-sample) I see that the only Prism NuGet dependency in the template is Prism.Dryloc.Maui

The [Prism.Maui NuGet source code repository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Maui) is archived and says it has been merged into the [main Prism git repository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). However looking at the main Prism git repository shows Prism.Maui build is failing, and the "NuGet Packages" section of the main README does not talk about any Maui package.

I searched for Prism.Maui on Nuget.org and found it but it's in the pre-release state and when searching in Visual Studio for macOS, it does not even appear.

My question is, is there production-ready support in Prism for .NET 6.0 MAUI on iOS and Android? And if so, which NuGet libraries should be pulled into the project(s)?

I tried searching for Prism.Maui in Visual Studio nuget package manager and it did not appear. I expect instructions for how to integrate Prism into a Maui app for iOS and Android.

Comment: you can use the pre-release version or wait or use xamarin forms

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is going out of support and everyone needs to be upgraded to MAUI by May 2024 or else they cannot release updates to the iOS app store. Getting the ball rolling on the upgrade process is urgent.

Comment: it's pre-release version, then, for you, I suppose, and hoping there's a stable release in time